# Waiting in a Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, loops, delay, wait

I have a function set up like this

```
awesomeFirePenguin: function(){
   // function does some stuff, not important
},
```

and I call it in a for loop like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
   this.awesomeFirePenguin();           
}
```

This works, the function is called `n` times, but the results of the function are shown immediately after each other. What I want is for the results to be shown after each other with a slight delay, like 100ms or so. Something klike this

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
   this.awesomeFirePenguin(); 
   // wait a while and then continue    
}
```

I tried using

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    window.setTimeout(this.awesomeFirePenguin(), 100);
}
```

and `window.setInterval(this.awesomeFirePenguin(), 100);`, but both only execute the function once.

Comment: The unique thing about my problem is the way I have my function set up and I can't change that. If I use the solutions in the other question, I end up with what I describe at the end of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` can take functions as arguments, but what you were doing is *calling* them. Thus, they were receiving not the function, but its return value as an argument.

If you want to delays to stack, you can just multiple the timeout delay by whatever loop index you're currently at.

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){
    window.setTimeout(this.awesomeFirePenguin.bind(this), 100 * i);
}
```

Comment: Might be necessary to wrap the function or use `.bind()` to preserve the context (`this`)

Comment: @finrod: No prob, and welcome to StackOverflow! If you haven't already, check out the quick [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by voithos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841546/535871) is probably the simplest. You can also use an asynchronous execution library like [Clumpy.js](http://www.tumuski.com/code/clumpy/overview/), where you could write your code as:

```
var clumpy = new Clumpy({delay: 100});
var i;
clumpy.for_loop(
    function() { i = 0; },
    function() { return i < n; },
    function() { ++i; },
    this.awesomeFirePenguin
);
```

It's also possible to do this using a closure and a self-invoking function, but it's ugly code that's hard to understand:

```
(function loop(i, f) {
   setTimeout(function () {
      f();
      if (--i) loop(i, f);
   }, 100)
}(n, this.awesomeFirePenguin));
```

It's possible to write something using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, but it's not any easier to comprehend, although it probably eliminates the recursive calls.

Comment: Nice, interesting usage of recursion.